# I made a circle menu, but when i put it in my website, i couldn´t scroll anymore and the menu didnt shop up when i clicked on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

So recently I have been trying to create my own circle menu. I tested it in a new file and it worked. But when I put it in my website. I wasn't able to scroll up nor down anymore. And the menu did not work either as when I click on it, it doen't show any options...

I am new to coding, could someone please explain/help me fix it?

```js
$(function() {
  
  $(".menu-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $(".menu-overlay").toggleClass("open")
    $(".option1").toggleClass("open")
 $(".option2").toggleClass("open")
 $(".option3").toggleClass("open")
 $(".option4").toggleClass("open")
 $(".menu").toggleClass("open")

  });
 
});
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ff685d;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}



.menu-link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
}


.menu-line {
 background-color: #333;
 height: 2px;
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 2px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 transition: all 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
.menu-line-1 {
 top: 0;
}

.menu-line-2 {
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto;
 opacity: 1;
}

.menu-line-3 {
 bottom: 0;
}

.menu.open .menu-line-1 {
 transform: translateY(7px) translateY(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
}

.menu.open .menu-line-2 {
 opacity: 0;
}

.menu.open .menu-line-3 {
 transform: translateY(-7px) translateY(50%) rotate(135deg);
}

.menu-circle {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.menu:hover .menu-circle {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}
{ OPTION 1 }
.option1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 150px;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  opacity:0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.option1.open {
 opacity:1;
 visibility: visible;

}
.option1:hover .menu-circle {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}
{ OPTION 2 }
.option2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 77px; 
  left: 125px;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  opacity:0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.option2.open {
 opacity:1;
 visibility: visible;

}
.option2:hover .menu-circle {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}
{ OPTION 3 }
.option3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 125px; 
  left: 77px;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  opacity:0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.option3.open {
 opacity:1;
 visibility: visible;

}
.option3:hover .menu-circle {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}
{ OPTION 4 }
.option4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  opacity:0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.option4.open {
 opacity:1;
 visibility: visible;

}
.option4:hover .menu-circle {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="menu">
    <span class="menu-circle"></span>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">
      <span class="menu-icon">
        <span class="menu-line menu-line-1"></span>
        <span class="menu-line menu-line-2"></span>
        <span class="menu-line menu-line-3"></span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="option1">
  <span class="menu-circle"></span>
  <span class="menu-link">
  <span class="menu-icon"></span>
  </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="option2">
  <span class="menu-circle"></span>
  <span class="menu-link">
 
  </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="option3">
  <span class="menu-circle"></span>
  <span class="menu-link">
  </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="option4">
  <span class="menu-circle"></span>
  <span class="menu-link">
  </span>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And also, as you can see, if you open the menu, the option fade in. But they don't fade out. Why? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scroll is not working because you just put the overflow hidden in a body in css, that means doesn't matter how much the page height it does not scroll it.

And one more thing you have to use webkit in css3 properties for browser supportability, and the way you are using a comment in css like `{ OPTION 4 }` it's wrong the format is `/* { OPTION 4 } */`.

You can alose write jquery in a short way instead of using multi times `toggleClass` just put the one class in all the div's in which you want to toggle class. For example I put the `navLinks` class in all the `option1, option2, option3, option4` class and toggling your open class

**check out the example below.**

```
    .navLinks.open {
        opacity:1;
        visibility: visible;

    }
    .navLinks:hover .menu-circle {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }



    <div class="menu">
        <span class="menu-circle"></span>
        <a href="#" class="menu-link">
            <span class="menu-icon">
                <span class="menu-line menu-line-1"></span>
                <span class="menu-line menu-line-2"></span>
                <span class="menu-line menu-line-3"></span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="option1 navLinks">
        <span class="menu-circle"></span>
        <span class="menu-link">
            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="option2 navLinks">
        <span class="menu-circle"></span>
        <span class="menu-link">

        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="option3 navLinks">
        <span class="menu-circle"></span>
        <span class="menu-link">
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="option4 navLinks">
        <span class="menu-circle"></span>
        <span class="menu-link">
        </span>
    </div>

$(function() {
    $(".menu-link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".menu-overlay").toggleClass("open");
        $(".navLinks").toggleClass("open");
        $(".menu").toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes that worked!. But now my menu doesn't stay in place and you can scroll it of the screen. I tried "position: fixed;"but that made it disappear..

Comment: after position: fixed; give them z-index: 999;

Comment: Yay it worked. But there is still one issue i can't seem to fix myself. The menu itself won't show up...

Comment: can you please share your website link that I can see the problem.??

Comment: I'm not hosting the website. Is there a way to send the file to you? Or how do I place code in a comment, or should I create another question?

Comment: Hi, Trojo are your using position fixed on every class which is perfectly wrong, 
you must have to know about how to use positions in css, check out the link below and read carefully about positions.

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-the-position-property-in-css-to-align-elements-d8f49c403a26